# How do I Increase the Swap Size?

Tags: swap

I just recently increased my RAM, so I wanted to increase the swap size too.  I know Elementary OS is based off Ubuntu, so I've been following Ubuntu information since there isn't much documentation for this stuff for Elementary OS specifically.  I have 8GBs of ram now, and from what I understand, Ubuntu recommends that you allocate 11GBs of ram if you're planning on using hibernation, or 3GBs if you're not using hibernation.  Is this true for Elementary OS too?

> https://itsfoss.com/swap-size/

Anyways, I was following the following guide to increase the swap size:

> https://linuxhandbook.com/increase-swap-ubuntu/

But when I got to the part where we use the follocate command to increase the swap file size, I get the following error:

```
fallocate: fallocate failed: Invalid argument
```

I figured I'd allocate 11GBs of space just to be safe, so I was using the following command:

```
sudo fallocate -l 11G /dev/dm-2
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?  Is 11GBs a good size for the swap for Elementary OS with 8GBs of RAM?  Am I getting GiB mixed up with GB in the follocate command?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the output of `swapon --show`. Swap can be a file or it can be a partition and that changes the steps you need to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Generally a swap file would not be written in `/dev`, which contains device APIs, but in the root (`/`) directory. So long as you don’t mind having a file there, you can do something like this:

```
sudo fallocate -l 12G /swapfile
```

<sup>**Note:** The `12G` size is different from what you specified not because 11GB is “wrong”, but because I generally leave 4GB of swap for buffers on machines that need to hibernate. Feel free to set any value you are comfortable with.</sup>

From here it would be a good idea to verify the file exists and is the right size with:

```
ls -lh /swapfile
```

You should see a single file of the same size you specified in the `fallocate` command.

The next step is to *enable* the swap file. This is done by setting the permissions:

```
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
```

Then marking the file as being for swapping purposes:

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

If everything goes properly, you’ll see something like:

```
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 12288 MiB (12884901888 bytes)
no label, UUID=6ecf2854-2ab9-4437-1ee0-577e740897ff
```

Now you can tell the system to use that space:

```
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

You can verify Elementary OS is using the swap file with the `swapon` command:

```
sudo swapon --show
```

You should see something like this:

```
NAME      TYPE   SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file 12288M   0B   -2
```

Finally, to make your swap file operational at boot time, you need to edit your `fstab` (File System Table) file:

```
sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

<sup>**Note:** Feel free to use any text editor you are familiar with. It does not need to be `vi`.</sup>

Add this to the end of the file:

```
/swapfile     none     swap    sw   0   0
```

While this *looks like* a lot of steps, it’s not too bad when you step through the process to see what’s going on

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer!  I just have two questions.  First, should I delete the old swapfile being used that was in /dev/dm-2?  Second, in the fstab file, there is already a line that says "/dev/mapper/data-swap  none  swap  defaults  0  0".  Should I delete that line and replace it with the one you mentioned?

Comment: To answer your questions: (1) Yes, but only *after* you have disabled it and restarted the system (to ensure it's not being accessed) (2) If you do not have a swapfile at `/dev/mapper/data-swap`, then I would suggest first commenting out the line by adding a `#` to the very start. If nothing breaks, then you can delete the line 